# I am having trouble aligning inputText + commandButton with the rest of my form fields

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a simple VF form to register an enquiry. The only extra functionality I have in the form is an email checker.

The inputText field by itself falls in line with the form fields above it, but as soon as I add the commandButton it seems to mess up the alignment completely. I have tried a few things, using margin-left style attribute, putting the button in a div and outputPanel - I have not been able to resolve it so far.

If anyone could help it would be very appreciated.

[image: As you can see from the screenshot, the inputText box and commandButton are skewed to the left which looks horrible.]

```
<apex:page controller="EnquiryForm2Controller" lightningStylesheets="true">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>    
    <apex:form id="theForm">
        <apex:pageblock title="Register an Enquiry" >
            <apex:pageMessages />
            <h3><font color="red">Please use the 'Check email' button so you do not create a duplicate contact.</font></h3>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="What property are you interested in?">
                <apex:inputField value="{!ll.ListingForForm__c}" />                
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Contact Details" >
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel value="First Name"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Applicant.FirstName}" required="true"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Last Name"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Applicant.LastName}"  required="true"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Lead Source"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Applicant.LeadSource}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Phone" />
                <apex:inputField value="{!Applicant.Phone}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

             <apex:actionRegion renderRegionOnly="false"> 
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Email" for="email_input"/>                 
                <apex:inputText value="{!emailid}" required="true" id="email_input" />                      
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                 <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                 <apex:commandButton action="{!ValidateEmail}" value="Check email" reRender="theForm" />       
                 </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>                                  
                 </apex:actionRegion>
                                                                                                                                      
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
         </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: did you consider using an onchange for the inputText and calling an actionFunction?  This way you could eliminate the commandButton

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, I have considered this but I still need the apex:actionRegion so that it can check the inputted email while disregarding the required fields in the form

Answer (score 0):

The action region breaks certain kinds of constructs in Visualforce. How I've resolved this in the past is to include a new page block section:

```
         <apex:actionRegion renderRegionOnly="false"> 
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="Email" for="email_input"/>                 
            <apex:inputText value="{!emailid}" required="true" id="email_input" />                      
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
             <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
             <apex:commandButton action="{!ValidateEmail}" value="Check email" reRender="theForm" />       
             </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>                                  
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
             </apex:actionRegion>
```

As long as you don't include a title or other attributes, it will act as if it is part of the section above it, and have correct formatting consistent with the rest of the page.

Comment: Ah that is annoying. Thanks for this, it looks better than before but it is still too far left and not in-line. Very odd.